# Merge two files and specify fields using awk

Tags: awk

I want to merge two files and output them.

So file0.txt and file1.txt are merged.

However, the column of file1.txt is appended to the end.

```
$ cat  file0.txt 
   Name: vSwitch0    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic0    Portgroups: VM Network, Management Network
   Name: vSwitch1    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic1    Portgroups: VM Network 2
   Name: vSwitch2    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic2    Portgroups: VM Network 3

$ cat  file1.txt 
vmnic2  nvmxnet3  Down  0  half
vmnic0  nvmxnet3  Up  10000  full
vmnic1  nvmxnet3  Up  10000  full
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { temp[FNR]=$2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5; next }; {print ($0) " " temp[FNR]}' <(sort file1.txt)  <(sort file0.txt)

   Name: vSwitch0    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic0    Portgroups: VM Network, Management Network **nvmxnet3 Up 10000 full**
   Name: vSwitch1    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic1    Portgroups: VM Network 2 **nvmxnet3 Up 10000 full**
   Name: vSwitch2    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic2    Portgroups: VM Network 3 **nvmxnet3 Down 0 half**
```

I've tried but failed.
I want to do something like below

However, I don't want to use join or paste.. I will only using awk command .

```
   Name: vSwitch0    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic0  **nvmxnet3  Up   10000 full**  Portgroups: VM Network, Management Network 
   Name: vSwitch1    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic1  **nvmxnet3  Up   10000 full**  Portgroups: VM Network 2 
   Name: vSwitch2    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic2  **nvmxnet3  Down 0  half**      Portgroups: VM Network 3
```

OR

Second my question

Is it even possible like this?

```
cat file1.txt 

vmnic0  nvmxnet3  Up   10000  Full
vmnic1  nvmxnet3  Up   10000  Full
vmnic2  nvmxnet3  Down 0      Half
vmnic3  nvmxnet3  Up   10000  Full
```

```
# cat file2.txt 
Name: vSwitch0    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic0            Portgroups: VM Network, Management Network
Name: vSwitch1    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic1            Portgroups: VM Network 2
Name: vSwitch2    MTU: 1500    Uplinks: vmnic3, vmnic2    Portgroups: VM Network 3
```

Is it possible to output something like this?

```
vmnic0  nvmxnet3  Up   10000  Full  Name: vSwitch0  MTU: 1500  Portgroups: VM Network, Management Network
vmnic1  nvmxnet3  Up   10000  Full  Name: vSwitch1  MTU: 1500  Portgroups: VM Network 2
vmnic2  nvmxnet3  Down 0      Half  Name: vSwitch2  MTU: 1500  Portgroups: VM Network 3
vmnic3  nvmxnet3  Up   10000  Full  Name: vSwitch2  MTU: 1500  Portgroups: VM Network 3
```

Comment: without `sort` you would have to collect all records of `file1.txt` into array indexed by field like `vmnic0`, while preliminary `sort` by the needed field will prepare your files to have records one in front another allowing you just enumerate the fields for output

Comment: No, Do not change order of vmnic lines in file1.txt, It is assumed that file1.txt is not sorted.

Comment: if `file1.txt ` should be as is then your final output is incorrect: it has `nvmxnet3  Up   10000` as 1st row, while it should be `nvmxnet3  Down  0` (from the 1st row of  `file1.txt `)

Comment: You're saving 3 fields from file1 (`$2 FS $3 FS $4`) but somehow outputting 4 fields from file1 (`nvmxnet3  Up   10000 full`). Please fix your example to make sure it's accurate.

Comment: thanks for the advice. 
added "FS $5".. what do you think of my second question?

Answer (score 1):

Replace Portgroups with the text you want to add.

```
awk '
NR==FNR { temp[FNR]=$2 FS $3 FS $4; next }
{gsub(" Portgroups:", temp[FNR]" Portgroups:"; print}
' <(sort file1.txt)  <(sort file0.txt)
```

Comment: you're missing a closing `)` to the gsub(). You'd have to make sure that file1.txt doesn't contain a `&` for this to work.